# Compile Error Encountered when creating Many-to-Many Relationship with CoreData Accessors

Tags: ios, core-data, accessor

I have a many to many relationship in CoreData.

Teams has team info and is linked to Schedule which has meet info. A team can have many conferences and a meet has multiple teams attending.

CoreData generated NSManagedObject Sub-classes like this:

```
//
//  ScheduleDetails.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class SchoolRecords;

@interface ScheduleDetails : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * meetCity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *whatTeams;
@end

@interface ScheduleDetails (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addWhatTeamsObject:(SchoolRecords *)value;
- (void)removeWhatTeamsObject:(SchoolRecords *)value;
- (void)addWhatTeams:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeWhatTeams:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

I create an instance of SchoolRecords* in category class of SchoolRecords and try to call:

```
[ScheduleDetail addWhatTeamsObject:thisSchool].
```

But get the compile error:

```
No known class method for selector 'addWhatTeamsObject:'
```

I am importing ScheduleDetails.h

Apple's instructions say I am supposed to add an @dynamic addWhatTeamsObject (I presume), but I cannot figure out where to implement that.

When I try to implement the @dynamic attribute, I simply get two compile errors.

I also tried implementing addWhatTeamsObject in a TableViewController where a method returns an instance of a SchoolRecords*. I get the same error.

I can add more detail if that would be helpful. I have looked around for an example of how these relationships can be established but am coming up blank.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[ScheduleDetail addWhatTeamsObject:thisSchool];
```

should be

```
[thisSchedule addWhatTeamsObject:thisSchool];
```

where

```
ScheduleDetails *thisSchedule;
```

is the *instance* that you want add a team to.

(All necessary `@dynamic` declarations should already be in the Xcode generated managed object subclass files. There is probably no reason that you have to add your own.)

Comment: I have been banging my head against my desk for hours. That is so simple, but now makes sense because you have to set both sides of relationship, I guess. Thanks! No pre-compile or compile errors!

For others who might have problem: I simply passed in the appropriate instance of ScheduleDetails from my TableViewController's fetch method.

Comment: @PhillipOReilly: You only have to set one side of the relationship (it does not matter which one). The inverse relationship is then updated automatically.